# Sort and index matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, indexing

I have a variable **data** which is a **1xn double** (n>15), something like this:

```
50.12 55.93 58.78 67.36 67.90 100.12 2.35 168.73 ...
```

First, I would like to keep only the first 15 highest values in **data** while removing the rest. This is easy to do. However, the complication is that each of the value in **data** is associated with a set of x y z coordinates in **coord**. **coord** is a **3xn double**, something like this:

```
8 9 15 42 32 56 3
4 25 36 7 89 21 3
5 1 25 75 79 20 66...
```

For instance, the coordinates of data(1,1) would be coord(:,1) and the coordinates of data(1,6) would be coord(:,6). The challenge here is that I would also like remove the corresponding coordinates in **coord** that are associated with the removed values in **data**. That way, I would end up with **1x15 data** and **1x15 coord**. I thought about doing this:

```
M=vertcat(data,coord) ;
```

then **sort M** by the first row and keep only the highest 15 values of the first rows to end up with 4x15. Finally, I split **data** and **coord**.

My questions are:
1. How can I sort M according to the first row in a way that the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th row are also reorganized accordingly?
2. My proposed solution seems messy. Does anyone have an elegant solution?

Comment: Would it be simpler to just put all of the information you need into a single data structure?  Coordinating related arrays/matrices is a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` will tell you where each element of the sorted array came from, you can use this to reorganise the columns of `coord`

```
[dataSorted,I] = sort(data,2,'descend')
dataTop15=dataSorted(1:15)
coordTop15=coord(:,I(1:15))
```